# Parametrization for the curve on cylinder $y = 7 - x^4$ that passes through the point $(0, 7, -3) $when t = 0 and is parallel to the xy-plane

Tags: parametric

Can you help me?

So far I have turned $y = 7-x^4$ into $\langle1, 1, 0\rangle$ and used it to make the equation $L = (0, 7, -3) + t(1, 1, 0)$. I know this is wrong, but I just don't know what, and I know it has to do with $y = 7-x^4$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $y=7-x^4$ defines a _surface_, not a curve, given the implication that this is all in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @alex.jordan yes, yet he is clearly asking for the curve defined by intersecting said surface with the plane $z=-3$

Answer (score 0):

When you choose your curve, $z$ can take any value, so just choose $f(t)=(t, 7-t^4,-3)$. Clearly, the curve is parallel to the xy-plane (a curve is parallel to a plane if it lies in a plane parallel to the plane)...no reparametrization is necessary and certainly we don't need to think about lines through the point $(0,7,-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Required parametrization of curve parallel to base curve defined by  first two coordinates is

$$ x= t , y = 7 -t^4 , z = -3 $$

$x,y $ relation shows that it is a fourth order parabola. Also no $x,y$ is involved in $z$. So it is a surface obtained by extruding the higher order parabola parallelly drawn along $z.$ Such independent two coordinates satisfy not a *curve* but the full surface, which are called cylinders.

The base parabola *curve* is shown in green, and  the *surface* generated upto $z=-3$ is yellow.The upper edge $z=-3$ is the *curve* your question.

[image]